# Swift 4 SpriteKit: How to prevent the .alpha property of a parent node from effecting the children nodes?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift4, skspritenode

I have a SKSpriteNode which is the parent node of an SKLabelNode. When I change the .alpha property of the SKSpriteNode it also changes the .alpha property of the SKLabelNode. This is not the behavior I would like to implement, I would like the SKSpriteNode to have a .alpha of 0.5 (which is the background of the text), and then the SKLabelNode to have a .alpha of 0.9. Does any know how I could create this functionality for my game?

Here is my code for the label:

```
    let TheLabel = SKSpriteNode()
    TheLabel.zPosition = 6
    TheLabel.color = UIColor.black
    TheLabel.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    TheLabel.alpha = 0.5

    let TheText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Noteworthy")
    TheText.text = "TheUserNameOfTheOpponent"
    TheText.fontSize = 25
    TheText.fontColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
    TheText.zPosition = 7

    TheLabel.size.width = TheText.frame.size.width * 1.2
    TheLabel.size.height = TheText.frame.size.height * 1.2
    TheLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 - (TheLabel.frame.width / 2), y: self.frame.height - 50)
    TheText.position = CGPoint(x: TheLabel.size.width / 2, y: TheLabel.size.height / 2)
    TheText.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    TheText.verticalAlignmentMode = .center

    self.addChild(TheLabel)
    TheLabel.addChild(TheText)
```

Here is a screen shot of what it looks like now: [CurrentLabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8g99.png)

Here is a screen shot of what I would like it to look like : [DesiredLabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrH8I.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the alpha directly on the **TheLabel**. Instead of it, use the below line of code which will apply transparency to **TheLabel** without affecting its child views.You need to change 1 line of the code.

```
TheLabel.color = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
```

This will solve your problem. And also remove this line of code

```
TheLabel.alpha = 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with **SpriteKit** before but can you try:

• Instead of `TheLabel.addChild(TheText)` do `self.addChild(TheText)`

• Then try to anchor the text to be right on top of the label

Comment: Thanks, this is defiantly a good approach and certainly works, however since I'm planning on adding multiple labels to the game Imrul's answer works a bit better and requires a little less code.